# Asymptotics of $\int_1^\infty a^x x^{-x} dx$

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Let
$$I(a) = \int_1^\infty \frac{a^x}{x^x}\,dx.$$
What is the asymptotic growth of $I(a)$? I am primarily interested in seeing if there is an upper bound of the form $I(a) = O\big(\exp(a^c)\big)$, with $c<1$.

Comment: That is probably for large $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint (basically Laplace method): substitute $x=(a/e)+t\sqrt{a}$ (note that $x=a/e$ is the maximum of the integrand) and take $a\to\infty$. With all the necessary checks for DCT to apply, we get $$\lim_{a\to\infty}e^{-a/e}I(a)/\sqrt{a}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-et^2/2}\,dt=\sqrt{2\pi/e}.$$

Comment: Again, I just want to mention that this is only valid if $a > e$. For small asymptotic, I think you need a different approach...

Comment: @Gregory: Since I see "asymptotic growth", I automatically assume $a\to\infty$. The question doesn't specify this explicitly, but it looks like "telepathy works" ;)

Comment: Fair point. I think the small $a$ case is a little more annoying because it is not in the integral range. I am not even sure what the best idea is, short of just setting $a = 1$.

Comment: After little bit of thinking, I see that $I(a)\asymp -a/\log a$ as $a\to 0^+$.